# QRCode generating not displaying react native

Tags: react-native, qr-code

I am trying to generate a qrcode using the [`react-native-qrcode-svg`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-qrcode-svg) library.

My code is extremely simple :

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import QRCode from 'react-native-qrcode-svg'

const qrcode = (props) => {
    return (
        <View>
            <QRCode value="https://www.google.com" />
        </View>
    )
}
export default qrcode
```

However, when I execute the code I get the following error : `Exception thrown while executing UI block: -[NSDictionaryM firstObject]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600009dd4780`

I am having trouble understanding the issue because I followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iShltk7YCfM) step by step and it is not getting the error.

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Did you have any success fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**:

The reason is conflict peer dependency. Package already has [PR](https://github.com/awesomejerry/react-native-qrcode-svg/pull/166) to resolve it. And [temporary solution](https://github.com/awesomejerry/react-native-qrcode-svg/issues/169#issuecomment-1375654063) until it's merged. But as far as I see it's all done (01/19/23). So just try latest version 6.2.0.

**Outdated answer**:

You should install latest `react-native-svg`, which `react-native-qrcode-svg` depends on. In my case latest expo version 47 doesn't work with `react-native-svg` 12.5.0 installed by `react-native-qrcode-svg` 6.1.2. So after expo upgrade I did `npx expo install react-native-svg` and solve the problem.

Comment: Hello. Please could you paste your exact version of your dependencies? I'm having this problem too but it doesn't work even with your answer.

Comment: @NewUser134 I've updated my answer. My dependencies for now are the same as in temporary solution linked. But it should work well with latest version.